# Spring Boot + Liquibase: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, connection-pooling, liquibase, spring-jdbc

I'm using Liquibase in all my projects, I really love the way it handles db updates, but recently I'm having this issue:

```
liquibase                                : Successfully acquired change log lock
liquibase                                : Successfully released change log lock
liquibase                                : Could not release lock

liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.releaseLock(StandardLockService.java:283) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar!/:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:218) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar!/:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar!/:na]
.
.
.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
.
.
liquibase                                : Failed to restore the auto commit to true
.
.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 16,913 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 89 milliseconds ago.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.clearInputStream(MysqlIO.java:899) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2477) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
```

I have 3 apps running on my server. One of them running for about 2years. The second running for 2 months and the third one is new.

They are all Spring Boot applications.

This started happening when I want to update the jar of the second app, I stopped the old jar, run the new one and I can not get it to start with the error above.
Then I run the old jar of the same app and it started just fine. I try stopping and restarting this old jar and a few times I get the error above but most of the times it started just fine.

I try restarting the server (all three apps start as services with system boot) but none of them successfully start because of the same error. Not even the one running for 2 years. I stop all other apps and try again with this long-lasting app, it kept failing until it started.

Could it be a memory issue? I'm using a DigitalOcean droplet with 1 Core and 2gb RAM.

Also, what I've notice is that when it successfully start the logs looks like:

```
liquibase                                : Successfully acquired change log lock
liquibase                                : Reading from myDataBase.DATABASECHANGELOG
liquibase                                : Successfully released change log lock
```

Note the statement between the acquisition and release of the lock. I also suspect about a timing issue, between acquiring the lock and reading the changelog. But don't know if I can increase that time or how can I do it.

## UPDATE

I don't known the source of the issue, but after updating the `liquibase-core` to **v3.7.0** all the apps started correctly

## UPDATE 2

About the previous update, I was testing as is not that the problem is solved, is just less frequent. But it has happen

## IMPORTANT UPDATE 3

After some digging I realize that by the same time this happen, the team was playing around with DB Connection Pool. The `application.properties` files contain this:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

Sadly I don't understand much about DB Pool. But what raise my attention was the last line about the `auto-commit`. The last time this error pops up. I disable all those lines and the app started fine. I don't know if it was just coincidence or not.

Thank you very much!

## UPDATE 4

I'm back to square one... I don't know how to solve this any clue would be appreciatted

## UPDATE 5

I updated mysql-connector-java to v8.0.15. My server has MySQL v5.6.33. I'm still having this issue and now I can not restart my app.

After the above change, now the exception ends with:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 10,036 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 10,036 milliseconds ago.
.
.
.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket is closed
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.AbstractSocketConnection.getMysqlInput(AbstractSocketConnection.java:72) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.clearInputStream(NativeProtocol.java:833) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

## UPDATE 6 - WORKAROUND SOLUTION

In a moment of clarity I decided to **disable** liquibase from my project, by setting `liquibase.enabled=false` in the `application.properties`. Now I can start/stop/restart the app anytime with no problem. As I only use liquibase to mantain the DataBase, and the changes I made are executed (the problem is when releasing the lock), I will enable Liquibase just to update the schema and then disable it to run the app

## UPDATE 7 - I think I've solve it

I kept stoping and starting the apps over and over and every time I did it I get the `Socket is closed` so I began to make my head around a timing issue... From the exceptions thrown I notice that every time it says that:

> The last packet successfully received from the server was xxxx milliseconds ago.

The smallest value I get of those milliseconds ago was **10.085** and by chance I have some logs of the same app from time ago when this issue never pop-up. From those logs statements I meassure the time between acquiring the change-log-lock and releasing it. To my surprise it was around **9 seconds** and never above that.

So I login to `mysql` console and issue:

```
show variables LIKE '%timeout%';
```

Which gave me a list of the defined timeouts. And there it was `connect_timeout` was the smallest and set to **10 seconds**. It has to be it.

I googled how to set that value. I've try creating a file `/etc/my.cnf` and adding to it:

```
[mysqld]
connect_timeout=20
```

Then restart mysql with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

But when I log back to the mysql console the value was still *10*. So in the mysql console I issued this other command:

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=20;
```

And the value was updated (I don't know if this will persist after a restart)

I restart mysql again and... voilà! Now the apps start normally with liquibase enabled. I'm happy! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept stoping and starting the apps over and over and every time I did it I get the `Socket is closed` so I began to make my head around a timing issue... From the exceptions thrown I notice that every time it says that:

> The last packet successfully received from the server was xxxx milliseconds ago.

The smallest value I get of those milliseconds ago was **10.085** and by chance I have some logs of the same app from time ago when this issue never pop-up. From those logs statements I meassure the time between acquiring the change-log-lock and releasing it. To my surprise it was around **9 seconds** and never above that.

So I login to mysql console and issue:

```
show variables LIKE '%timeout%';
```

Which gave me a list of the defined timeouts. And there it was **connect_timeout** was the smallest and set to **10 seconds**. It has to be it.

I googled how to set that value. I've try creating a file /etc/my.cnf and adding to it:

```
[mysqld]
connect_timeout=20
```

Then restart mysql with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

But when I log back to the mysql console the value was still *10*. So in the mysql console I issued this other command:

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=20;
```

And the value was updated (I don't know if this will persist after a full server restart)

I restart mysql again and... voilà! Now the apps start normally with liquibase enabled. I'm happy! :-)

Answer (score 1):

We were working with MySQL **8.0.19**. For me, it were only a query which used to fail with the exception `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket is closed`.

Found that for MySQL **8.0.19**, there was a bug reported with a similar stack trace of mine - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99234

After upgrading MySQL server to **8.0.21**, it started working ! No other changes.

Hope it helps for folks who have spent quite some time with selected query(ies) not working and having the same error, and tried out various other options.

Answer (score 0):

have you solved it yet?

I had a similar problem and solved it by forcing Liquibase to execute in synchronous mode. 
Was your spring boot app generated by jhipster by any chance? If so, take a look at DatabaseConfiguration and change from AsyncSpringLiquibase to SpringLiquibase

Comment: Hi! It was not generated by jHipster. I think I partially solve it with 2nd update, at least I can live with that. How's that about the synchronous mode? I didn't know about it. Can you elaborate/edit your answer?